# Close existing form on opening another form

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am working in compact framework 3.5,i am working on windows mobile application.

form1.cs

```
internal void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
    form2 obj = new form2();
    obj.ShowDialog();
    /////other code
}
```

form2.cs

```
public void backbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1 obj = new form1();
    obj.ShowDialog();
    /////other code
}
```

Initially i am in  `form1` and i am navigating to form2.In form2,a back button is there and on clicking backbutton i need to show the from1.Now i can show the form1 on backbutton click,but i need to close the previous opened form1.

I tried with `this.Close()` and `this.Dispose()`. This makes me exist from my application.

How to do this in compact framework.

Comment: Your application is exiting because you're closing your main form.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger form1 is not the main form,it is next to main form.

Comment: I think the issue you need to address first is a possible design flaw. Do you have good reason for wanting to actually close form1 and then open a new instance, or would it make more sense to simply hide and then reshow form1 when form2 closes?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger For some reason I need to kill the existing instance from memory and open a new one.Please help me.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger I can do that but if user opens any folder other than my application in form2 then go back from form2 will exit from application.For this reason i am creating a new object from form2.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "open any folder in form2"? It sounds like that may be where your bug truly is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56662/discussion-between-royal-and-leon-newswanger).

Comment: @LeonNewswanger i had given the explantion for that in chat.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger my problem is if user is in form2 and if he click Start and press internet explorer from device,the brower will open.After that if user click out application from Start button the application open and it shows the form2.From there if user hit back buton it takes him to exit the application.To avoid that i created an object and open a new form1. here i need to kill the existing fom1 object

Comment: @LeonNewswanger Yes.Since it is exits i am opening new form on clicking back button of form2

Answer (score 1):

Best way to work with that kind of things is using a singleton. When you show your first form, you instance the first form, then you show the second creating it instance and hiding the first one (use hide(), not close(), then your instance will still on memory). On back button click, you only have to hide() the second, and show() the first.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend instead of creating new form1 from form2, just close form2 and go back to form1:

form2.cs:

```
public void backbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

form1.cs:

```
internal void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 obj = new form2();
    obj.ShowDialog();
    /////other code
}
```

Comment: I can do that but if user opens any folder other than my application in form2 then go back from form2 will exit from application.For this reason i am creating a new object from form2